# spring-data-jpa pagination returing null values on third page

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

In My Spring MVC application, I am using spring-data-jpa with MySql Data Base.
For a data table trying to implement pagination.

Like this
[image]

On the table there are 191 records,and 'id' is the primary key - the value of starting from 10, 11, 12 ---- 199, 200.

My each page contains suppose **10** records.

following is the code I am using to fetch only 10 records from the table.

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(firstResult, maxResults);   
Page<User> findAll2 = repository.findAll(pageable);
```

For Page 1 -> firstResult = **1** and maxResults = 10
              Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10);
              Here I am getting 10 records, the **id 20 to 29**
              But I am expecting from **10 to 19**

For Page 2 -> firstResult = **11** and maxResults = 10
              Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(11, 10);
              Here I am getting 10 records, the **id 120 to 129**
              what about other records.

Now
For Page 3 ->firstResult = **21** and maxResults = 10
              Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(21, 10);
              Here I am NOT getting any record.
              [image]

```
          All values are null.Not sure what I am missing.please help me on this.
```

Answer (score 1):

The first number is the `page` not the `firstResult`. So you should start with

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 10);
```

Then:

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10);
```

And so on.

When you say

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(21, 10);
```

You're asking for page 21, which you don't have, so it returns null.